# Why is Jquery Resetting Form Values

Tags: php, jquery, forms, reset

Is there any way to prevent Jquery from clearing form values?

I have made the following Jquery script which essentially sends the forms POST data to a php function and then redirects to a new page if the PHP output was a success or shows an error if it wasn't.

```
   $('#update').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'function.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   success: function(data)
   {
   if (data === 'Success') {
   window.location = 'acc.php';
   }
   else {
   alert('Please try again.');
  }

}

});

});
```

And the form values are filled by echoing out a php variable like so:

```
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
```

Everything is fine on page load, however after I updated the values of the fields via the front end form and hit submit Jquery deletes all values of the fields, sends blank values back to php (which get entered into the DB) and redirects to the new page as it is getting the Success message back.

I removed the Jquery and tries sending the form directly to php and it worked fine, so it is definitely a Jquery issue.

EDIT: The PHP variables are pulled from another function, the do initially show in the fields correctly when that particular page is first loaded.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: `serialize()` only works on `form` elements, but it looks like `#update` (and therefore `this`) is a button. Furthermore, preventing the default behavior of clicking the submit button does not prevent the form to be submitted. Listen to the `submit` event on the form instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're (probably - would need to see page HTML to know definitely) calling the `.serialize()` on the wrong element.

You have a `click` event handler bound to an element with an id of `update`. I'd guess that's either a button or link that you want the user to click on to send the AJAX request. Inside the context of that event handler function, `this` will be the element you clicked on, so calling `$(this).serialize()` will attempt to serialize the button or link, not the form.

What you want instead is either:

```
$('#id-of-your-form').serialize()
```

or, if you only have one `<form>` element on your page, you could use:

```
$('form').serialize();
```

Incidentally, this seems like the kind of thing that should be handled by server-side validation (so it rejects blank values).

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I initially tried the form id however it still cleared the values, and then just tried 'form' seeing as there is only one on the page and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

try changing:

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

to

```
data: $("#your_form_id").serialize(),
```

OR

```
$('form').submit(function() {      
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'function.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhir, I used Anthony's solutions, which was essentially the same.